# how can i make placeholder through javascript which run in all browser even ie6

Tags: javascript, placeholder

i have already made placeholder for input "value attribute" but the value attribute are using for some other purpose so how can i make for other attributes such as placeholder or any other self-made ..

my code for value attribute work in all browser..so any one suggest me how can i make something like this for placeholder or any other input attribute.

```
/*For placeholder*/ 
function ClearPlaceHolder(input) {      
    //var plc = document.getElementById(input.id).value;
    if (input.value == input.defaultValue){
        input.value = "";
        document.getElementById(input.id).style.color = '#444444';
    }
}

function SetPlaceHolder (input) {
   if (input.value == "") {
        input.value = input.defaultValue;
        document.getElementById(input.id).style.color = '#c9c9c9';              
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing something like that for any other attribute doesn't seem to make any sense, as it's only the `value` attribute that the user can edit. What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: i simply want to make a placeholder something like HTML5. which work in all browser even ie6 .so any other simple java script you know then plz tell me .......only tell me javascript code jQuery or other library i am not using in my project.

Comment: What would you want the "placeholder" to do, if it wouldn't be a placeholder for the value?

Comment: In my project there is a requirement of placeholder but there is a restriction to use jQuery or other external library.. so i have only on option "JavaScript".. and i have implemented for same but developer use "Value" attribute so that's the problem i have to use another one input attribute.

Comment: But what do you want to do? A regular placeholder is shown when there is no value, so how do you want it to work with any other attrite? When, where and how would you want to show it?

Comment: in a simple word i want to write the code as i written above but the problem with placeholder attribute is that i am unable to detect default placeholder value as i done with value attribute.(input.DefaultValue). so any thing which hold the default placeholder value so after which i use to set will be usefull for me..

Comment: Ah, now it's getting clearer... So, it's not the `value` attribute that is the problem, but the `defaultValue` attribute? You don't need to store the place holder text in an attribute at all, you can keep that in the script that handles the events, if you bind the events with code instead of attributes.

Comment: yes now u actually understand my problem but i am not know how to do this so if u give me code for that so it's very useful for me because i am not expert in this field i am just beginner so please help me for giving me code....thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: thanks for your great help...really it's very useful for me...thanx a lot...i got yr code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using event attributes to call existing functions, you can use a function to bind events. Then you can simply send the default value into the function:

```
function initPlaceHolder(input, defaultValue) {
  input.onfocus = function() {
    if (input.value == defaultValue){
      input.value = "";
      input.style.color = '#444444';
    }
  };
  function remove() {
    if (input.value == "") {
      input.value = defaultValue;
      input.style.color = '#c9c9c9';              
    }
  }
  input.onblur = remove;
  remove();
}
```

Usage:

```
<input type="text" id="me" />

<script type="text/javascript">
initPlaceHolder(document.getElementById("me"), "Enter name");
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/RFm5e/

Answer (score 0):

I guess this can get you started.

```
Qty1 : <input type="text" placeholder="numbera" name="qty" id="qty"/><br>
Qty2 : <input type="text" placeholder="numberb" name="qty" id="qty2"/><br>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($.browser.msie){
            var inpElements = $('[placeholder]');
            $(inpElements).each(function(){
                $(this).css('color','#aaaaaa').val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
            });
            $('[placeholder]').one('focus', function(){
                $(this).val('');
            });
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: sorry for this but this help is useless for me because i don't use jQuery in my project so please tell only with javascript..

Comment: Its difficult to create browser specific code without jquery, if you want to support for older browsers

Comment: so how jQuery work for old browser because at backend it also use javascript.

Comment: It's more optimised for sure than writing just plain javascript